# What all does git worktree copy?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I have a pretty big git repository- 21G, when I create a new worktree for a local branch, I find that it takes particularly long creating a new dir of approx 5GB... is this normal?

- What all does git worktree copy over?
- Is there a more optimal workflow to reduce the disk/checkout overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Those 5GB should be mainly your files as checked out in their new branch: Git has to copy them all to their new folder through [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

Refs are shared across all working trees (`/path/main/.git/refs/heads/master`).

The optimal workflow is that hopefully, creating a new worktree is not something you have to do every five minutes, so it could be sxripted/scheduled in order to be done, for instance, during the night and ready for you in the morning.